# how to remove the label in the linechart in primefaces 3.3.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to remove the label in the linechart. For that i have tried by giving empty label but in the graph it dispayed color box without the label .

```
ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
boys.setLabel("");
```

If i tried without setting the label. It displayed color box with "null" as label.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but you could hide the entire legend box using css. Something like this:

```
.jqplot-table-legend {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue

```
yourChart.options = {
          legend: {
            display: false,
           }
      };
```